# Why the date-label is on input with Materialize?

Tags: html, date, label, materialize

I am developing a web application with `Materialize` and I need to use `date` but the `label` text is on of the `input`, How can I resolve it?

It is all the simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->


       <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
       <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
       <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
       <!--Import materialize.css-->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

       <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   </head>

   <body>
       <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
       <div class="input-field col m6">
           <i class="material-icons prefix">picture_in_picture</i>
           <input id="hello_id" type="date"/>
           <label for="hello_id">Hello, this text is a test</label>
       </div>  
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!